# How to convert array-buffer post content to original value?

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

Am exporting web page as PDF file by using JSPDF plugin,then send it as array-buffer datatype to backed,the problem is i can't convert the array-buffer to a PDF file again to use it as email attachment

This code is for exporting page as PDF and send id as array buffer to back-end:

```
var file = pdf.output('arraybuffer'); 
var data = new FormData();

data.append("data" , file); //pdf file generated from jspdf plugin
data.append("action" , 'action_name'); 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'post','ajax_url_to_backend', true );
xhr.send(data);enter code here
```

What i did in backend:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
unpack("C*",$data)
```

I expect the output a PDF file ready to download or send it as attachment.